# How to replace all matching patterns only if it does not match another pattern?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to replace a substring that matches a pattern, only if it does not match a different pattern. For example, in the code shown below, I want to replace all '%s' but leave ':%s' untouched.

```
String template1 = "Hello:%s";
String template2 = "Hello%s";

String regex = "[%s&&^[:%s]]";

String str = template1.replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(str);

str = template2.replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(str);
```

The output should be:

```
Hello:%s
Hello
```

I am missing something in my regex. Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to achieve your goal:

```
String regex = "(?<!:)%s";
```

It matches `%s` only if there is not a `:` right before it.